# Convertir fecha php

Tags: php, date

Tengo la siguiente fecha : "11-07-2017" dia/mes/año

Necesito convertirla a "yy/mm/dd" para insertarla en la bd mysql he intentando con esto sin resultados:

```
$date = 11-07-2017;
date_format($date,'Y-m-d');
```

Obtengo este error :

> Severity: Warning
>
> Message: date_format() expects parameter 1 to be DateTime, string
>   given

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Como el propio error indica, le estás pasando un `String` como parámetro cuando deberías de pasarle un objeto fecha.

Para ello, deberías utilizar la función `DateTime`:

```
<?php
    $date = new DateTime("11-07-2017");
    $fecha = date_format($date,'Y-m-d');
    echo $fecha; //Devuelve 2017-07-11
```

Si quisieras que las separaciones fueran con barras entonces deberías poner:

```
$fecha = date_format($date,'Y/m/d');
echo $fecha; //Devuelve 2017/07/11
```