# Como convertir un string en una fecha con PHP

Tags: php, date, datetime

¿Alguien me podría decir como convertir un `string` con una fecha es este formato `"2000-01-01 00:00:00"` a un objeto de tipo `Date`?

La fecha la obtengo así de una consulta a una base de datos **mysql**.

Sé que debe ser una tontería, pero no consigo hacerlo.

Comment: Hola Javier. No es una tontería. ¿Qué has intentado? ¿Qué errores has tenido? Mira [ask] y [mcve] para más info. Un saludo

Comment: Aqui tienes varias preguntas en el sitio sobre conversiones del estilo: [1](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/90258/convertir-de-fecha-string-en-espa%C3%B1ol-a-ingles-con-formato-datetime), [2](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/83481/convertir-fecha-php), [3](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/13456/c%C3%B3mo-cambiar-el-formato-de-fecha-en-php). Un saludo

Comment: Posible duplicado de [Convertir fecha php](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/83481/convertir-fecha-php)

Answer (score 4):

Este ejemplo te puede servir.

```
 <?php 

  $Fecha =  "2018-03-27 08:15:00";
  echo date("jS F, Y", strtotime( $Fecha)) . "<br>"; 
  // salida 27th March, 2018
?>
```

[Formatos de fecha](http://php.net/manual/es/datetime.formats.date.php)
En este link estan los formatos de salida que le podes dar.

Comment: Hola Patrick. Es mejor esperar a que el autor explique qué problemas especificos tiene. Y además, te falta explicar la respuesta. Mira [answer] para más info. Un saludo

Answer (score 0):

Simple como:

```
$fecha = date("Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime($aquilafechastring)), PDO::PARAM_STR);
```

En la pagina de PHP puedes revisar la [tabla de formato de Fecha](http://php.net/manual/es/function.date.php).

Comment: puedes poner que significa cada caracter? por ejemplo yo no sé que significa la `i`

Comment: Claro. En la pagina de PHP la puedes revisar.
[enlace de  tabla de formato de Fecha](http://php.net/manual/es/function.date.php).

Comment: perfecto lo agrego a la respuesta, ya que el sistema te la está marcando como de baja calidad, espero que con ello ya no la marque

Answer (score 0):

Para hacer conversiones de formatos me gusta usar la clase DateTime (http://php.net/manual/es/class.datetime.php).

Algo como esto:

```
$fecha = "2018-03-29 15:20:40";

$dt = new DateTime($fecha);
print $dt->format('d/m/Y'); // imprime 29/03/2018
print $dt->format('H:i:s'); // imprime 15:20:40
```

Acepta los mismos formatos que la función `date()`